# Pandas - Id group by condition

Tags: pandas

help solve the task on Pandas.

In this table, you need to add a column with group numbers by condition.
If "qnt_cumulative" = 0 then this is a new group.

P.S.
The table shows the number of purchased and sold shares.
If "QNT_cumulative" = 0, then the operations on this "Ticker" ended.

Example below.
Thanks!

[Example of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZSpc.png)

Comment: *"In this table, you need to add a column with..."* No, *you* need to do that...

Comment: What is "the task"? What's your question about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code which uses `binary serach` to do what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'qnt_cumulative': [2,3,2,0,-250,-500,12,23,0,12,4,32,1,0,12,3,23,0]})
zero_indices = np.where(df['qnt_cumulative'] == 0)[0]
print(zero_indices)
df['group_id'] = df.apply(lambda row: np.searchsorted(zero_indices, row.name, side='left') + 1, axis=1)
print(df)
```

An alternative `for loop` implementation is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'qnt_cumulative': [2,3,2,0,-250,-500,12,23,0,12,4,32,1,0,12,3,23,0]})

zero_indices = np.where(df['qnt_cumulative'] == 0)[0]
zero_indices = np.append(-1, zero_indices)
zero_indices = np.append(zero_indices, len(df))
print(zero_indices)
group_number = 1
res = np.empty(0, dtype=int)
for i in range(1, len(zero_indices)):
    a = np.empty(zero_indices[i] - zero_indices[i-1], dtype=int)
    a.fill(group_number)
    group_number += 1
    res = np.append(res, a)
df['group_id'] = pd.DataFrame(res)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
           qnt_cumulative  group_id
0                2         1
1                3         1
2                2         1
3                0         1
4             -250         2
5             -500         2
6               12         2
7               23         2
8                0         2
9               12         3
10               4         3
11              32         3
12               1         3
13               0         3
14              12         4
15               3         4
16              23         4
17               0         4
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the alternative is working! =)

Comment: @st0rmy You're welcome, Please check and accept my answer as solution for your question if you liked it :D

Comment: @st0rmy Did my first solution have any errors or it wasn't outputing what you wanted? I edited my first solution and now it should work.

Comment: Both solutions work great!
At the moment I have little reputation to respond, thank you!